# How can I set the first and second page as cover in ssrs report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have one report in that there are multiple sub reports I need to set first page in that report is cover page with the image. Is this possible?

I need this first and second page and from third page needed the paging. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have the main report with the sub reports.  Just put the image on the top of the report and make sure to add a page break.  You may have to put the image within a rectangle for that option.